# Django: parametrizing db_table for inheritance

Tags: django, inheritance, metaclass

I want to set the `db_table` Meta class attribute in a base class so that all inherited classes will have their names in it, similar to how Django treats `related_name` model field attribute:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'prefix_%(class)s'
```

So the inherited model:

```
class SubModel(BaseModel):
    pass
```

will have db table `prefix_submodel`.

Is that possible? Can the Meta class access the inheriting class' model name?

Comment: Have you tried it yet, and it's failing? On a quick glance, it looks like it *should* work...

Comment: sure. it raises `TypeError: format requires a mapping` during syncdb.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't do that. It is not that simple to have same table to store for multiple classes.

What you need is probably [djeneralize](https://github.com/2degrees/djeneralize) project.

From the examples:

```
class Fruit(BaseGeneralizedModel):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name

class Apple(Fruit):
   radius = models.IntegerField()

   class Meta:
       specialization = 'apple'

class Banana(Fruit):
   curvature = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)

   class Meta:
       specialization = 'banana'

class Clementine(Fruit):
   pips = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   class Meta:
       specialization = 'clementine'

which then allows the following queries to be executed:

>>> Fruit.objects.all() # what we've got at the moment
[<Fruit: Rosy apple>, <Fruit: Bendy banana>, <Fruit: Sweet
clementine>]
>>> Fruit.specializations.all() # the new stuff!
[<Apple: Rosy apple>, <Banana: Bendy banana>, <Clementine: Sweet
clementine>]
```

Comment: thanks, what `djeneralize` does is impressive. imo, it should be in the core of django. but what i want is to simply set a prefix for the table names that are inherited from the same model.